# How can I hide "what's hot" in Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus

Is there any way to hide the "What's hot" section in Google Plus without using external programs (like ADBlock and stuff like that)?

Comment: I don't see anything on Google+ that would allow you to do that natively. Your best bet is probably a custom style sheet that will suppress that section for you.

Comment: Yeah, I feared that...

Comment: Related topic: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/reader/thread?tid=416517096be0bc56&hl=en

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24714/how-to-disable-completely-hot-on-google-feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible without using some sort of outside script. Google currently does not offer any options to remove this section.