# How do I completely disable the "Hot on Google+" feature?

Tags: google-plus

Is it possible to completely disable the Google+ feature called "Hot on Google+" that makes some posts of people not present in your circle appear on your stream?

This is an example:

[image: Screenshot of a Hot on Google+ post]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is. Click on "What's Hot" in your left sidebar and a volume slider will appear in the upper right corner. Slide this all the way to the left, like this:

[image: Volume Slider]

And no "What's Hot" posts will appear in your main stream anymore.

Comment: Thank you! I never thought to go in there because that sounded like even more of what I already didn't want.

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit puzzled by this at first.

They've changed it now, and it appeared that all you could do was set it to "less", but there's also a tick box to turn it off.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: I've added a screen shot. The functionality is essentially the same; they've just changed the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

They keep changing fast.

It seems that they don't want many users to turn this feature off. That's why they've bit of hidden it. E.g. For a brand page, there is simply no option to go to 'Explore' page (even if you just copy paste the link, you are parked on the main G+ page, not brand page).

And, for main Google+ page (not brand page), even when you went deep, and turned off, you may still see some unwanted posts as I'm doing. Sorry for not posting SSs.